# How to find the first 3 minimums of a list of numbers

Tags: list, loops, for-loop, numbers, min

I want to know how to find the first 3 or 4 smallest numbers in a list of numbers without sorting the list and without removing elements. I have found some code below which does a fine job finding the first 2 smallest numbers(mins):

```
def second_smallest(numbers):
    m1, m2 = float('inf'), float('inf')
    for x in numbers:
        if x <= m1:
            m1, m2 = x, m1
        elif x < m2:
            m2 = x
    return m2
```

I am, however, having a hard time modifying the code to give me the third smallest or 4th smallest number. Here is my modified code below which seems to work sometimes but not all the time:

```
m1, m2, m3= float('inf'), float('inf'), float('inf')
    for x in min_of_summed_vals:
        if x < m1:
            m1, m2 = x, m1
        elif x < m2:
            m2 = x
        elif x > m2 and x < m3:
            m3 = x
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Have you considered finding the nth smallest number by running through the list n times, for the first n-1 times, removing the smallest? On the nth loop, the smallest item is the nth smallest number of the original list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def third_smallest(numbers):
    m1, m2, m3 = float('inf'), float('inf'), float('inf')
    for x in numbers:
        if x <= m1:
            m1, m2, m3 = x, m1, m2
        elif x < m2:
            m2, m3 = x, m2
        elif x < m3:
            m3 = x
    return m3
```

This should work for third smallest.  You can apply similar logic for fourth smallest.  Actually the list m1,m2,m3 is a sorted list and iterating through each element you are inserting x in this list, if x falls within the boundaries.

To extend this logic to nth element you can use insertion sort logic to insert x to the m1.m2.m3..m<sub>n</sub> list.

Comment: I can't rate it since my rep is too low. How do i accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this algorithm for find the k-th maximum/minimum into an array of unsorted elements with worst case linear time:

> kthSmallest(arr[0..n-1], k)
>
> 1) Divide arr[] into ⌈n/5rceil; groups
>   where size of each group is 5     except possibly the last group which
>   may have less  than 5 elements.
>
> 2) Sort the above created ⌈n/5⌉ groups and find median     of all
>   groups. Create an auxiliary array 'median[]' and store medians     of
>   all ⌈n/5⌉ groups in this median array.
>
> *// Recursively call this method to find median of median[0..⌈n/5⌉-1]*
>   3) medOfMed = kthSmallest(median[0..⌈n/5⌉-1], ⌈n/10⌉)
>
> 4) Partition arr[] around medOfMed and obtain its position.
>        pos = partition(arr, n, medOfMed)
>
> 5) If pos == k return medOfMed  6) If pos < k return
>   kthSmallest(arr[l..pos-1], k)  7) If poa > k return
>   kthSmallest(arr[pos+1..r], k-pos+l-1)

[Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallestlargest-element-unsorted-array-set-3-worst-case-linear-time/) you can find a complete explanation (with a proof of the linear time in worst case) and an implementation in C++